# Authentication in Pyrogram user session with two-factor authentication

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I have several accounts and bots associated with them. I'm creating a separate bot within which I want to authorize existing accounts as user sessions and interact with BotFather to gather information about which bots are associated with which accounts, create new ones, etc.
Everything related to authorizing an account and creating or reconnecting a session for an account **without** a two-step verification password is working without any issues.
However, if a two-step verification password is set on the account, I'm unable to perform session.sign_in() (with the correct password, of course).

The bot, through states, receives all values from me, including the account password if it exists. In pseudocode, it looks like this (data is the FSM dictionary; I just won't write async with state.proxy() as data:):

```
    data['number'] = message.text
    data['app_id'] = str(message.text)
    data['app_hash'] = message.text
    if message.text not in [0, "0"]:
        data['password'] = message.text
        app = Client(name=f"{data['number'].lstrip('+')}", api_id=data['app_id'], api_hash=data['app_hash'], password=data["password"])
    else:
        app = Client(name=f"{data['number'].lstrip('+')}", api_id=data['app_id'], api_hash=data['app_hash'])
    await app.connect()

    client = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
    client[data['number']] = app
    sent_code_obj = await app.send_code(current_data['number'])
    phone_hash = sent_code_obj.phone_code_hash
    data['phone_hash'] = phone_hash
    data['app'] = client

    await app.sign_in(phone_number=data['number'], phone_code_hash=data['phone_hash'], phone_code=message.text)
```

In this case i got an error:

```
pyrogram.errors.exceptions.unauthorized_401.SessionPasswordNeeded: Telegram says: [401 SESSION_PASSWORD_NEEDED] - The two-step verification is enabled and a password is required (caused by "auth.SignIn")
```

Also I was trying somthing like that:

```
    data['number'] = message.text
    data['app_id'] = str(message.text)
    data['app_hash'] = message.text
    if message.text not in [0, "0"]:
        data['password'] = message.text
        app = Client(name=f"{data['number'].lstrip('+')}", api_id=data['app_id'], api_hash=data['app_hash'])
        await app.check_password(password=data['password'])
    else:
        app = Client(name=f"{data['number'].lstrip('+')}", api_id=data['app_id'], api_hash=data['app_hash'])
    await app.connect()

    client = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
    client[data['number']] = app
    sent_code_obj = await app.send_code(current_data['number'])
    phone_hash = sent_code_obj.phone_code_hash
    data['phone_hash'] = phone_hash
    data['app'] = client

await app.sign_in(phone_number=data['number'], phone_code_hash=data['phone_hash'], phone_code=message.text)
```

In this case, when I reach await app.check_password(password=data['password']), I receive an error:

```
The key is not registered in the system. Delete your session file and login again (caused by 'account.GetPassword')
```

**The question is what am I doing wrong and how should I authenticate my own account, but with a password, by entering this password into my own bot.**